# Receiving a null value from android in Web service

Tags: android, web-services, spring-mvc

I am developing an android application.Here I am facing an issue with posting values to rest service.I used Namevaluepair to bind values to post the data.

```
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("businessName", businessname));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address1", address1));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("businessphone", businessphone));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("zipCode", zipCode));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("locationcount", locationcount));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("businesstypeid", businesstypeid));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstnname", firstname));
```

like this.When I am pring these values here in android client its printing properly.But at server I am getting null values.

```
  try {
            // http client
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            // Checking http request method type
            if (method == POST) {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

               try
                {
                // adding post params
                if (params != null) {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                    System.out.println("this is post method.....................");

                    System.out.println(url);
                    System.out.println(params);
                }
                }

                catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try
                {
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
                }
                catch(ClientProtocolException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

here is my ServiceHandler class.can you please give me suggestion why I am getting this kind of issue..Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: where you have declared and added params in your code,i can't see this in your posted code here

Comment: how have you declared your params

Comment: the above and below code are in different classes?

Comment: is ServiceHandler class is a local class of this activity or not

Comment: Are you sure that service accepts your `form-parameter` format? or should it be in JSON format?

Comment: it is JSON format I think